# Show/hide ribbon button on CRM 2011 for users

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using CRM-2011 on premises. I need to show Advanced Find Button for some users (3 or 4), otherwise hide. Can I do it with a custom JavaScript rule? If so, then how? If no please give other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ribbon Workbench to do that:

http://www.develop1.net/public/post/Dynamically-ShowHide-a-standard-ribbon-button-based-on-a-form-value.aspx

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/110385.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the below blog, it provides step by step procedures for hiding Advanced find button.

http://happyconfii.blogspot.in/2014/11/hiding-advanced-find-button-based-on.html